# iOS UIPrintInteractionController printToPrinter Contacting printer

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing, flutter

I'm currently developing an app using direct print through `UIPrintInteractionController` `printToPrinter` method but when I launch a print order a popup comes up saying:

> Printing to "my-printer.local."
>   Contacting printer...

But I don't have any print order in my printer, and the app is stuck with this popup (tap the "Cancel" button do nothing).

Here is my method to print:

```m
- (void)directPrint:(nonnull NSString*)name withPrinter:(NSURL*)printerURL {
  UIPrintInteractionController* controller = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
  [controller setDelegate:self];

  UIPrintInfo* printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
  printInfo.jobName = name;
  printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
  controller.printInfo = printInfo;
  renderer = [[PdfPrintPageRenderer alloc] init:channel];
  [controller setPrintPageRenderer:renderer];

  UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler =
      ^(UIPrintInteractionController* printController, BOOL completed, NSError* error) {
        NSLog(@"Handler completed: %d", completed);
        if (!completed && error) {
          NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u", error.domain, (unsigned int)error.code);
        }
        self->renderer = nil;
      };

  UIPrinter* printer = [UIPrinter printerWithURL:printerURL];

  BOOL status = [controller printToPrinter:printer completionHandler:completionHandler];

  NSLog(@"Print status: %d", status);
}
```

The `printerURL` comes from `UIPrinterPickerController` `presentAnimated` method.

`status` variable is `true`.

I tried with an iPhone Simulator + Printer Simulator, here is the printer logs for one method call:

```
[21/Feb/2019:14:40:49 +0100] [Client 46] Accepted connection from 192.168.1.131:57092 (IPv4)
[21/Feb/2019:14:40:49 +0100] [Client 46] Encrypting connection.
[21/Feb/2019:14:40:49 +0100] [Client 46] Connection from 192.168.1.131 now encrypted.
[21/Feb/2019:14:40:49 +0100] [Client 47] Accepted connection from 192.168.1.131:57093 (IPv4)
[21/Feb/2019:14:40:49 +0100] [Client 47] Encrypting connection.
[21/Feb/2019:14:40:49 +0100] [Client 47] Connection from 192.168.1.131 now encrypted.
```

**NOTE 1:** printing using `UIPrintInteractionController` `presentAnimated` works perfectly (using simulator or real device).

**NOTE 2:** the following code is used inside a Flutter plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not related to the iOS printing functionality but comes from the plugin implementation of the direct print.
See here for more info: https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/issues/37

It's the current usage of callback and thread that makes the UI unresponsive.